# two scale colors in maps ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I am ploting maps on `ggplot` and I would like to plot two different `scale_fill_gradient`, after reviewing ***several*** posts of stack overflow I couldnt reach the desired results.

From a `shapefile` I read into a dataframe a map of `spain` there are two columns where every row is only informed in one of the regions, never in both. The point is to represent both concepts in the same plot with two `scale_fill_gradient`.

This is my the code for the actual picture:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=long, y= lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes_string(color= "ratio_quan"), size = 0.2)+
  scale_color_gradient(low ="yellow", high ="blue", na.value="white")+
  geom_polygon(aes_string(fill= "ratio_qua"), size = 0.2)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low ="pink", high ="red", na.value="blank")
```

[image]

As far as I understood only one fill option can be provided, for that reason I used `scale_color_gradient` and `scale_fill_gradient`, but there are border distinction in one scale and fill in the other one, in stead of that what I want to accomplish is the following:

[image]

As you realise, in this case both concepts are filled by colors in the polygons.

Comment: You can't have two fill scales in ggplot natively. However, if you check out the `ggnewscale` package (which is now on CRAN) you can achieve this. It's not possible to give a worked example because you haven't shared any sample data.

Comment: The data was very complex to share, I took that risk :(, thanks about that advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution 1

#### Accomplish the requirements

By @Allan Cameron .

This issue is solved by `ggnewscale`, this question has been addressed previously in lot of threads at stack-overflow previously and were solved in alternative ways.

By importing the library `ggnewscale` with the function `new_scale_fill()` a new scale color can be applied in an easy way.

```
library(ggnewscale)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=long, y= lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes_string(fill= "ratio_quan"), size = 0.2)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low ="yellow", high ="blue", na.value="white")+
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_polygon(aes_string(fill= "ratio_qua"), size = 0.2)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low ="pink", high ="red", na.value="blank")
```

## Solution 2

#### Alternative

This classic approach is by using to arranged plots with `grid.arrange` which is less fancy but could be more interpretable.

```
  p1 <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=long, y= lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes_string(fill= "ratio_quan"), size = 0.2)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low ="yellow", high ="blue", na.value="white")
  p2 <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=long, y= lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes_string(fill= "ratio_qua"), size = 0.2)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low ="yellow", high ="blue", na.value="white")
  grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow = 1)
```

As a result two plots with isolated scales are used on the same plots.

Comment: This is a good solution to OP's problem.  I can confirm the approach works fine with, for example, [US population data](https://remiller1450.github.io/s230s19/Intro_maps.html).  I read in that data, sorted population into groups of alphabetically "A-M" vs. "N-Z" states, then created separate scales for those two groups of states using the population as the value.  Works like a charm (although not the best way to show the data, honestly).

Comment: You're right, in order to offer an alternative and interpretable option a grid arrange alternative is offered.