# How to have a different color spectrum for two variables in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting two variables with the following code:

```
ggplot()+
   geom_point(data=subset(afc_reopening, key == "mean_spend_all"),
              aes(x=day_after_reopening, y=mean_spend_cases * 100, color = winner2016)) +
   stat_smooth(data=subset(afc_reopening,key == "mean_spend_all"),
               formula = y~as.numeric(x), se = F,
               aes(x=day_after_reopening, y=mean_spend_cases*100, color = winner2016))+
   geom_point(data=subset(afc_reopening, key == "new_case_rate_07da"),
              aes(x=day_after_reopening, y=mean_spend_cases,),) +
   stat_smooth(data=subset(afc_reopening,key == "new_case_rate_07da"),
               formula = y~as.numeric(x), se = F,
               aes(x=day_after_reopening, y=mean_spend_cases, color = winner2016),)+
   facet_wrap(.~deciles_income,scales = 'free')+
   theme(legend.position = 'top')+
   ylab('Change in consumer spending relative to 14th January and Past 7 Days New Cases Average')+
   labs(title = "Change in spending and Past 7 Days New Cases Average in US Counties Grouped by Income Decile") +
   scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-100,100))
```

The code results in the following graph:

[image]

The only problem I am having with the graph is that the points for both values are in the same color. I would like to have different color spectrum for spending and for cases (with each still being grouped by the winner of the 2016 election). How do I do this in ggplot?

Here is the output of the dput() function:

```
structure(list(day_month_year = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18364, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18392, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18427, 
18392, NA, NA, NA, 18329, NA, 18427, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 18301, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18294, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 18441, NA, NA, NA, 18378, NA, NA, 18420, 18294, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), tzone = "Europe/Prague", class = "Date"), deciles_income = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
3L, 5L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 9L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
5L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA, 
NA, 2L, NA, NA, 3L, 9L, NA, NA, NA, NA), winner2016 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Donald Trump", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Hillary Clinton", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Hillary Clinton", "Hillary Clinton", NA, 
NA, NA, "Hillary Clinton", NA, "Donald Trump", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "Hillary Clinton", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Hillary Clinton", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Hillary Clinton", NA, NA, NA, "Hillary Clinton", 
NA, NA, "Donald Trump", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), key = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "new_case_rate_07da", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "mean_spend_all", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "new_case_rate_07da", "new_case_rate_07da", 
NA, NA, NA, "mean_spend_all", NA, "mean_spend_all", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "new_case_rate_07da", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "new_case_rate_07da", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "new_case_rate_07da", 
NA, NA, NA, "mean_spend_all", NA, NA, "new_case_rate_07da", "new_case_rate_07da", 
NA, NA, NA, NA), mean_spend_cases = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.98999975990396, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.163540740740741, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 8.37364285714286, 4.66982142857143, NA, NA, NA, -0.0154640434782609, 
NA, -0.0665955440414508, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12.0187207792208, 
NA, NA, NA, -0.187623043478261, NA, NA, 7.48311044417767, 0, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -75L), groups = structure(list(
    day_month_year = structure(c(18294, 18294, 18301, 18329, 
    18364, 18378, 18392, 18392, 18420, 18427, 18427, 18441, NA
    ), tzone = "Europe/Prague", class = "Date"), deciles_income = c(8L, 
    9L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 6L, NA), .rows = structure(list(
        57L, 71L, 50L, 39L, 16L, 67L, 35L, 26L, 70L, 34L, 41L, 
        63L, c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
        12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
        24L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 36L, 37L, 
        38L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 51L, 
        52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 64L, 
        65L, 66L, 68L, 69L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 13L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please consider providing a sample of your data or using a dataset already existing in R. As it stands, you're asking us to write code with no data, or to adapt your methodology to a different dataset (which may not meet your expectations).

Comment: OP, I think [the answer posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63441444/two-scale-colors-in-maps-ggplot) which uses `ggnewscale` can help answer your problem.  However, if you want more specific help, please share some of your data (via `dput()` please) or utilize a built-in dataset like `mtcars`, `diamonds`, or `iris` to create a representative example of your question.

Comment: Could you please use next code `dput(afc[sample(nrow(afc_reopening),75),])` and paste the output in your question in order to help you?

Comment: @Duck I have added it to the question